# Obtain statistics of CPU and memory usage from one cgroup

Tags: docker, monitoring, cpu-usage, cgroup

## Context

I have a system in which I have to check periodically usage:

- relative (percents) for `CPU`
- and absolute (GB) for `memory`.

## How it's currently implemented

Language we're using is `python`.

### system-wide `psutil`

For system-wide stats it's trivial since we can use `psutil.cpu_percent()` and `psutil.virtual_memory()`.

### `cgroup` (v1)

The problem is that sometimes the script is run inside container, and then we'd like to monitor usage of particular `cgroup` instead of system-wide statistics.

There's already implementation for `cgroups` in our system which bases on:

- for CPU:

  - `cpu.cfs_period_us`
  - `cpu.cfs_quota_us`
  - `cpuacct.usage`
- for memory:

  - `memory.usage_in_bytes`
  - `memory.limit_in_bytes`

### What I need

Here I need an answer for two questions:

- Is the present implementation based on reading values directly from files ok for `cgroup`?
- If no, are there any tools which supports obtaining such kind of information easily.
- If yes, how can I adapt this solution to `cgroup2`?

### Why current solution doesn't work for `cgroup2`

The main problem I have now is lack of support for `cgroup2` since current implementation is based on nested files structure.

#### `cgroup` on `Ubuntu 20.04`

```
$ cat /proc/mounts | grep cgroup
tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0
cgroup2 /sys/fs/cgroup/unified cgroup2 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/pids cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/memory cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb 0 0
```

#### `cgroup2` on `Ubuntu 22.04`

```
$ cat /proc/mounts | grep cgroup
cgroup2 /sys/fs/cgroup cgroup2 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
```

Comment: Why don't you use `/proc` filesystem? You mostly need to check correct file/folder.

Comment: @askyagi could you elaborate more on what should I look for in `/proc` to determine CPU and memory usage in my group?